# Legend location, similar to telephone

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

For years I have been wondering why the numbering of Python legend location makes no sense:

```
Location String Location Code
'best'          0
'upper right'   1
'upper left'    2
'lower left'    3
'lower right'   4
'right'         5
'center left'   6
'center right'  7
'lower center'  8
'upper center'  9
'center'        10
```

For me it would make much more sense to attribute the numbers as if they were on a cellphone:

```
Location String Location Code
'best'          0
'upper left'    1
'upper center'  2
'upper right'   3
'center left'   4
'center'        5
'center right'  6
'lower left'    7
'lower center'  8
'lower right'   9
```

Is there any way I can manipulate this in a script, which I can call every time I do plotting so I don't have to go tho the [matplotlib site](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) every time?

Or is there any change they will be changing it soon?

ps: What is the purpose of having both 'right' and 'center right' as legend location options?

Comment: Changing it now would cause a huge amount of backward breaking incompatibility... Why do the numbers matter so much to you anyway - why not just use the names?

Comment: @JonClements because I can't remember the names exactly.

Comment: If the numbers would follow other standards, like the numbers on your telephone, or on your numberpad on the keyboard, then yes, I would easily remember. With the names I an always doubting: "Is it 'top left' or 'upper left'?" Doing some basic plotting every several months or so I find myself forgetting the exact names of the legend location every time. Honestly, I can't be the only one having the same problem right?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're desperate, you can do something like

```
locations = [0, 2, 9, 1, 6, 10, 7, 3, 8, 4]

plt.legend(loc=locations[telephone_index])
```

(and if you're really desperate, you could even write a wrapper for `legend()`).

Comment: Me neither, but lots of code is only ever touched and used by a single person. That's a playground where anything is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers are essentially there for backward compatibility. Most examples on the matplotlib documentation have already been changed to use the text form.
For the text you only need to remember that

- the vertical direction comes first ("upper", "center", "lower") followed by the horizontal direction ("left", "center", right")
- There is no "center center", and that is simply "center".

---

You may of course print out this little picture [[*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317)]

[image]

and pin it to your screen.

---

A more consise way *would* be to use a "compass" notation like "N", "NW", "SE" etc. Which was already suggested [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/11174#issuecomment-386833679). I now proposed such solution [in this pull request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12679).

Comment: Great suggestion, this gives indeed an (indirect) solution to the problem

Comment: Do 'right' and 'center right' fall on top of each other? Why is 'right' shifted up a bit and 'center right' shifted outside of the figure boundaries? I find myself not being able to identify the difference between those two.

Comment: That is for readability of the figure. 5 and 7 are identical; and "right" is also only there for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I now [proposed](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12679) the use of a compass-notation.